# How to enter string characters in a node linked list using an array, then remove them?

Tags: java, string, linked-list, nodes

I am writing a program that accepts names (strings) from a user using node data structures, displays the names, then selectively deletes the names. (I want the input to be in a array). When the names are entered using a for loop and displayed the the program will ask me what I want to delete or what name to remove from the array.

This is my class:

```
 public class Node
{
    Node next;
    String data;

    public Node (String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

*What the program should do:*

Lets say I enter 5 names in a for loop.

```
Alex, George, Fryon, Storm, Hilbert.
```

Then when I entered it it will display:

```
Alex.
George
Fryon
Storm
Hilbert
```

Then it will ask what name should I delete?

```
(Alex)
George
Fryon
Storm
Hilbert
```

But I cant even enter them.

```
String[] contestant = new String [MAX];
head = null;

for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{ 
 System.out.println ("Enter a name:");
 name [0] = stdin.readLine ();

 node = new Node (name [i]);
 node.next = head;
 head = node;
}
```

And Im confused if nodes or linked lists relate to arrays. I was hoping to store it as a "node array", use a for loop to display it "like an array" and then "delete it using sorting like an array". But its honestly difficult.

Comment: Can you use standard container `LinkedList` or must write it by yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the following:

```
String name;
Node current = null;

while(true)
{ 
 System.out.println ("Enter a name:");
 name = stdin.readLine ();

if( name.equals("exit") ) break;

 if( current == null ) {
    current = new Node(name);
}
else {
   current.next = new Node(name);
   current = current.next;
}

}
```

Comment: How do you iterate since you don't have reference to the head now?

Comment: How do you make name a array?

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I amaze myself.

A array is a different data structure then a linked list. Ive been programming with arrays for so long that I didn't realize there were more efficient ones like circular linked lists.

.